# Website looks zoomed on load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a website for my tennis club: http://users.aber.ac.uk/dwd/aut/

Can anyone tell me why it looks zoomed in and push to the right? Click view source to see the HTML/CSS/Javascript as its quite a lot to post in the comment thread.

If you zoom out once that's what the site SHOULD look like.

Any ideas guys?
Dan

Comment: `If you zoom out once that's what the site SHOULD look like.` I had to zoom in for it to look centralized. Different users will access your site with different resolutions, keep that in mind. `=]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set the content to have an above average width and absolutely positioned it some distance from the left of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It looks lopsided because it's not properly centre-aligned (if you use the Ctrl+- shortcut it becomes more obvious)

If you remove `position: absolute;` from `#wrapper` it displays correctly centred for me (in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the font-size from the body CSS, and then remove `position: absolute` and `left: 12em` from your #wrapper div.

Comment: This worked and the site is now centered. However, its still zoomed in just not over to the left anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out why this is happening. Here's some more points, though:

- to truly centre a container, use a value of `auto` on the margin X/Y axes. You are doing this currently, but it's being undermined by the fact that you have also specified absolute positioning, so remove the latter
- incidentally, your current attempt to centre may work on your screen, but on a different resolution it will not, since you're essentially just bumping the page to the right by an arbitrary number of pixels
- whilst a target resolution is something every site designer has to decide for him/herself, the standard is to make the page work in 1024 * 768. Your page container is currently 1024 pixels in width along, with a further 32px padding added either side. Either reduce your width or take advantage of the CSS property `box-sizing`, which means any specified padding eats into your element's width, rather than adding to it